# TimeSpan Conversion

Tags: c#, timespan, seconds, minute

I want to convert minutes to seconds and at the moment I have a problem because in the minute textbox when I type 1.50 the outcome is 90 seconds which is wrong because 1.30 = 90 seconds

```
    private void MtoCbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (minTosecTextBox.Text != "Minutes")
        {
            minutes = Convert.ToDouble(minTosecTextBox.Text);
            TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
            resultSectextBoxtextBox.Text = span.TotalSeconds.ToString();
        }

        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Minutes");
        }
```

Comment: It is correct that 1.5 minutes, i.e. one minute and a half, correspond to 90 seconds...

Comment: one minute is 60 seconds. therefore `1.5*60 = 90`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To convert from seconds to minutes you simply need to divide by 60.0 (you need the decimal or it will be treated like an integer). If treated like an integer and you pass 30 seconds, 30/60 will equal 0.

Also use `double.TryParse` method. Right now if someone enters 1.50xx, your application will crash. Either use `double.TryParse` method or use a try catch mechanism or only allow numeric entry.

**EDIT**

This will accomplish what you want. I added a label to show the output but you can remove it.

```
double enteredNumber;
if (double.TryParse(minTosecTextBox.Text, out enteredNumber))
{
    // This line will get everything but the decimal so if entered 1.45, it will get 1
    double minutes = Math.Floor(enteredNumber);

    // This line will get the seconds portion from the entered number.
    // If the number is 1.45, it will get .45 then multiply it by 100 to get 45 secs
    var seconds = 100 * (enteredNumber - Math.Floor(enteredNumber));

    // now we multiply minutes by 60 and add the seconds
    var secondsTotal = (minutes * 60 + seconds);

    this.labelSeconds.Text = secondsTotal.ToString();
}

else
{

    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Minutes");
}
```

**EDIT 2**

**Some further clarification**

You are not converting minutes to seconds since if you were then 1.5 (1 minute and a half) would equal 90 seconds. This is logical and obvious. You are treating only the part before the decimal as minutes and the part after the decimal is to be treated as seconds (1.30 = 1 minute and 30 seconds = 90 seconds).
Therefore we only need to convert the part before the decimal to seconds and add  to it the part after the decimal.

Comment: This method will fail in all environments where the decimal separator is not a dot. "1.45" will, for example, return not 105 but 8700 seconds in most of Europe. Use the answer from @Paolo.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but why would someone enter 1.45 in, France for example, if a decimal for them is a comma. They will enter 1,45 (comma)  and it will produce 105 seconds. The reason I put this answer is because the OP wanted a simple answer. The above works and it will not fail. Try it and it will work in every local (environment).

Comment: No, 1.45 decimal minutes is 87 seconds, not 105. But I was mislead too and I even posted an answer along that line. However, by second thought, here we use comma as the decimal separator, and it would never be used as a time separator; in fact, entering 1,45 here would surely be read like decimal minutes, not 1 minute and 45 seconds. So I deleted my answer and upvoted @Paolo's because it will work everywhere, while yours will fail in most of Europe. Of course, if one operates in US environments only, this can all be ignored. But on this side of the pond, such issues are every day's concerns.

Comment: Sorry but that is not true. 1.45 equals 105 seconds since the OP said 1.3 equals 90 seconds. See my EDIT 2 for clarification.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote: 1.45 _decimal_ minutes is 87 seconds. 1.45 interpreted as 1 minute and 45 seconds is 105 seconds. Your code works only in an environment where dot is the decimal separator. Here, where comma is the decimal separator, your parsing to double ignores the dot and returns 8700 seconds. @Paolo's code doesn't have this limitation; it will work in any culture.

Comment: If comma is the decimal,  then enter a comma and it will give you the right result. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Point is that you would never enter a comma. You will enter an expression for a time, not for a decimal, and an expression with a comma would always be read by the user as a decimal value, never as a time. The only alternative to the dot is a colon, but even that is rarely used here.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably looking for something like the [TimeSpan.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:30");
```

This will produce a TimeSpan of 90 seconds.

There is also a [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which lets you specify a format string, so you don't have to specify the hours each time, and lets you even specify a dot as a separator:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("01.30", @"mm\.ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For the format string, see [Custom Date and Time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also note that you need to escape every character that is to be interpreted literally (hence the `\` before the `.`).

**Full code for your case**:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(minTosecTextBox.Text, @"mm\.ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
resultSectextBoxtextBox.Text = ts.TotalSeconds.ToString();
```

Comment: I cant enter the data myself so what can i put in the () the minutes where the value is stored or textbox where the value from from

Comment: You making this way too complicated for a person who has very little knowledge of c#

Comment: @MMobeenKhan I'm not making it complicated, I'm just trying to explain you how to make things better :) I think that using a library function is always better than writing your own string parsing.

Comment: var ts = TimeSpan.Parse( minutes ); how can i implement this with my current code and will i be able to put minutes inside the brackets

Comment: When I type 1.50 in the texbox i get error saying not right format input

Comment: To parse 1.50 you should use `m` instead of `mm` for the minutes. Check the link with the custom format strings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the conversion of the text differently.  You are converting "1.50" directly to a double, which is 1.5 and 1 and 1/2 minutes would be equivalent to 90 seconds.  If you want to allow the user to type "1.50" and mean, 1 minute and 50 seconds then you will need to split the string.  You could do something like this:

```
var split = text.Split('.');
int seconds = 0;
if (split.Length > 1)
{
    seconds = int.Parse(split[1]);
}
seconds += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(split[0]).Seconds;
```

Note - if you don't validate the text, than you could end up with this failing.  You should probably use a TryParse to validate the seconds. Parse can throw an exception.

Comment: TimeSpan.Parse is a better solution

Comment: @Winter - except that it would exception on this string as it is not in a valid format.

Comment: It was an example, he can change the format while with your example you can't.

Comment: @Winter - I can concede that. I am in agreement that TimeSpan.Parse is a better solution, and with ParseExact it is the right solution.  I had forgotten about the ParseExact method and I knew Parse would fail without doing things like string.Replace on the the input to change the '.' to ':' and also adding in the 0 hours part.  And as a side note - "he can change the format" is not always true. It may be that he is dealing with data from a other users or with some established format (although in this case I am guessing it is a homework assignment).