# Validating TimeSpan

Tags: c#, validation, timespan

I want to validate user input in the textbox, for example if its int throw error message before executing any code

```
private void MtoCbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TimeSpan.TryParse(minTosecTextBox.Text, out minutes))
        {

            var Minute = TimeSpan.ParseExact(minTosecTextBox.Text, @"mm\.ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            resultSectextBoxtextBox.Text = Minute.TotalSeconds.ToString();
        }

        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Minutes in correct format");
        }
    }
```

Comment: When do you want to throw exception when it's `int` or not `int`?

Comment: I want to be in 00.00 timespan format if anything else string or int or anything else i will show messgebox

Comment: @MMobeenKhan I know this is related to your other question. Honestly everyone made it too complicated. Go see my answer again, I added code and it will accomplish what you want [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952730/timespan-conversion/40952783#40952783)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Regex.IsMatch()` method to verify the string format:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(minTosecTextBox.Text, @"\d{2}\.\d{2}"))
{
   throw new ArgumentException("Input is not in correct format");
}
```

Comment: regex doesnt exist

Comment: add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: Just for my understanding if you can explain your reason for using these and what they do @"\d{2}\.\d{2} will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @mobeen It means minTosecTextBox's text content should match 2 numbers and then a decimal point and then 2 numbers. It is a regular expression and if you google regular expressions you will find plenty of helpful tutorials.

Comment: @rykamol two digits separated by a dot e.g. 22.33

Comment: @vendettamit Got it.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [TimeSpan.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784009(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of TimeSpan.TryParse

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact(minTosecTextBox.Text, @"mm\.ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out minutes);
```